# How to set article to default language if there is no translation for current language?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem when i add new language, and for that language there is no translation for article then i got an error. This is my code for article translation, so what i want is if there is no translation for `current_language_id`(if there is no that id in translation) to return translations for `default_language_id`. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
$default_language_id = 1;
 $article_trans = $article->translations()->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id){
        $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
      })->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about pre-checking the translation existence? Something like this...

```
$default_language_id = 1;

$language_exists = $article->translations()->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id){
        $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
      })->first();

$cur_language = !empty($language_exists) ? $language_exists : $default_language_id;

$article_trans = $article->translations()->whereHas('language',function($query) use($cur_language){
        $query->where('id','=',$cur_language);
      })->first();
```